# I get a Ipv6 address instead of v4

Tags: php, ip, connexion

I'm trying to get my user's IPv4 address when they connect to my site but it gives me the IPv6 address instead:

2a01:cb04:8ed3:b300:d3d:71c1:a883:5b61

And I want an IPv4 address that looks like this:

255.255.255.1

here is my code :

```
function get_client_ip()
    {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        } else {
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        }
        return $ipaddress;
    }
```

i've tried many approach but it keeps giving me weird ip adress. It was functionning on local but it is not on my server.

Comment: Their ISP is sending the IPv6 IP address. You most likely won't be able to get the IPv4 address if they aren't sending it.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the answer, so there is no possible way to correct it?

Comment: No. The IPv6 is correct, it's just not the one you'd like.

Comment: Okay I appreciate your feed back thank you a lot

Comment: You're getting the address that they used to connect to you. If the client has other addresses, there's no way to get it from the server.

Comment: IPv6 adoption is creeping up to the 50% mark globally, up past 70% in some countries. Best to get used to dealing with it sooner rather than later. https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html

Comment: This is like someone using their landline to call you, but you expect to see their mobile phone number show up in your caller ID instead ... simply makes no sense.

Comment: The funny thing about IPv6 is that it isn't an upgrade on top of IPv4. It's a completely different protocol. So if you're getting an IPv6 address that means you're using IPv6 protocol and IPv4 is not involved at all.

Comment: And how Can i change the protocol i'm using so i can get ipv4

Comment: You can change web server settings and no longer listen to IPv6 addresses. Of course, that will mean that your site is no longer available for people who use IPv6, which is quite an artificial restriction given that PHP can handle both protocols just fine, and all you may need on your side is to enlarge a database column (assuming you're storing values).